# Unable to find expected objects in VS 2015 memory usage profiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, clrprofiler, debug-diagnostic-tool

I have the following simple program which I am trying to use with VS 2015's Diagnostic Tools related to Memory Usage.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Goo();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Goo()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Foo(list);
        }
    }

    private static void Foo(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        foreach (var str in strings)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

While profiling this application's project, I took couple of snapshots and was expecting to see `1000` boxed `List<string>+Enumerator` objects. For example, I get this kind of information in JetBrains's `dotMemory` product. But for some reason, I am unable to see this information in VS's tool...I am obviously missing something...can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

As you can see in the above snapshot, I get information about the `mscorlib` module only where as I do not see any information about my executing program. What am I missing?...some more info below:

- I used `Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging` in visual studio
- After taking and opening the snapshot, I even unselected the option `Collapse small objects` to see if this was hiding any info, but that also did not help.

**Updated(responding to user answer)**:
I am using dotMemory version 4.4. Following is a snapshot of the data I get from it. NOTE: make sure to click the button `Collect Allocations` before you hit any key after seeing the `Begin` message

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects created in Goo and Foo already collected when you get snapshot at "End" point. I profiled this code with dotMemory 10.0.1 and also do not see any objects created in Goo and Foo methods.

**UPDATE:** In dotMemory you are looking at "Memory Traffic" view. [Memory traffic](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/help/Analyzing_Traffic.html) - are objects created and possible already collected to the point of time. dotMemory shows you a warning that it is not able to display collected objects. If you check ["Start collecting allocation data immediatelly" checkbox](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/51968486/profiler_conf_3.png) in the profiling setup dialog, dotMemory will show you that these 1000 objects were allocated and already collected. In VS Diagnostic Tools you are looking at **live** objects graph. I'm not very familliar with this tool, but it seems that there is no information about memory traffic.

If you look at live objects graph in dotMemory (["All objects" view](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/help/Analyzing_an_Object_Set.html)), you won't find these objects too.

Comment: I have updated my post with the snapshot of data captured in `dotMemory`. Make sure you click the `Collect Allocations` before you enter any key after the `Begin` line appears

Comment: @KiranChalla please accept answer if I answered your question

Comment: Thanks @Ed.ward...yes, it seems the VS diagnostic tools doesn't give the information about already collected objects.

Answer (score 2):

The memory analysis tool works by iterating all of the GC roots and traversing the object graphs from there - similar to what the GC does.  Once the method is out of scope, the local variable containing the enumerator is no longer a GC root. Any heap objects whose reference is stored in a local and is not referenced through another GC root are unreachable and essentially gone at that point.